# How can i access the find view by id of bottom nav outside on create in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am working on an application where I am using bottom navigation on Home where i have three fragments on the second fragment called **Post Ad** I have a button called **enter fragment zone** through that i enter into another fragment now when I enter inside another fragment now I don't want there to show the bottom navigation so to hide it I am using a method inside my main activity called **"setBottomNavigationVisibility"** where I am writing code to set the visibility of bottom nav. but the problem is that it is throwing the null pointer exception in the mainactivty's method saying that

**"void com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference"** on the method's line where i am setting the visibility

**code of MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NavController navController;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragmentContainerView);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_bottom_navigation_view);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

}

public void setBottomNavigationVisibility(int visibility) {

    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(visibility);

}}
```

On the above method when i am trying to setting the visibility on the line         **bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(visibility);** that's where it is thrwoing the exception

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentSecondBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  binding.getRoot();

    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(PageViewModel.class);

    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).setBottomNavigationVisibility(View.GONE);

    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment2_to_postad);
        }
    });
```

No Please guide me how can i solve this error.

Comment: How are you calling `setBottomNavigationVisibility`? add the code . and please remove all these images from question they do not relate to the question .

Comment: please check inside oncreateview of the fragment I am calling it please check on the line     ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).setBottomNavigationVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Something does not add up here cause `bottomNavigationView` seems to be null .. Are you sure this is the only call you are making to `setBottomNavigationVisibility`? you are not calling `new MainActivity()` Somewhere right ?

Comment: yes thiss is the only call i am making here

Answer (score 0):

in fragment you want hide bottom bar, just call this line in *onViewCreated*

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_main_bottom_navigation_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and when you leave fragment, call this line in *onDestroy* or *onStop* to visible bottom nav for another fragment:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_main_bottom_navigation_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: hey thank u for your response it is working but the problem is that it is not working on every fragment..dont why??

Comment: where it is not working the app is crashing throwing the null pointer exception

Comment: getActivity().findViewById work with all fragment inside MainAcitivity, if you navigate to a fragment is not in MainActivity, it's not work

Comment: no  i am using this only inside my activity main's only but

Comment: also when i return to  home fragment i want that the bottom navigation should be shown there but it does not??

Comment: I updated answer, you should set visible when you leave fragment

Answer (score 0):

do something like this, define interface

```
interface DashboardActivityDelegate {
    void hideBottomBar();
    void showBottomBar();
}
```

your activity must implement this interface

and in your fragment in which you want to hide bottom nav view do this:
declare global variable

```
private DashboardActivityDelegate dashboardActivityDelegate;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);
      if (context instanceof DashboardActivityDelegate) {
         dashboardActivityDelegate = (DashboardActivityDelegate)context;
      }

   }

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      if (dashboardActivityDelegate != null) {
         dashboardActivityDelegate.hideBottomBar();
      }
   }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      if (dashboardActivityDelegate != null) {
         dashboardActivityDelegate.showBottomBar();
      }

   }
```

Comment: hey thank you it is working but the problem is that when i return to main home fragment it did not show then also while it should be show there

Comment: bottom nav view not showing after return?

Comment: yes on the back press it is not showing on the home fragment

Comment: in your activity in function showBottomBar you add code for showing bottom nav view?

Comment: yes i have added the code  public void showBottomBar() {
        bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: please debug onDestroy function in your frament where bottom view need to be hide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247217/discussion-between---and-vivek-m-fauzdar).